# Doing simple comparison in dictionary with Python

Tags: python, dictionary, encryption, hash, comparison

```
import hashlib
import csv
with open ('C:\Python\Test\Hash.csv') as hash_file:
    # file_reader = csv.DictReader(hash_file)
    file_reader = csv.reader(hash_file)
    # counter = 0
    mydict = dict(filter(None,csv.reader(hash_file)))
    for i in range(1000,10000):
        bank_of_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(i).encode()).hexdigest()
        bank_of_hash={i:bank_of_hash}
    for counter in range(1,11):
        # counter +=1
        if mydict.values() == bank_of_hash.values():     
           print("This is your %s hash and this is the $a your decode" %(i,row))
        else:
            print("Password Not Found!!!")
```

Hi everyone, first of all, thank you for helping me. Second, it is so simple I don't know why it doesn't work.

1-I import the libraries.
2-opened it as hash_file
3-Here is my hash.csv file

- Jadi,9553627933b214db60798fe40d2b4f8497781d024f53d62dc1b12469b7d53784
  Jafar,58763bceaddcad6777063dd590cb8e50211b6bb7a11272110fef4060142ded20
  Jobra,08f88745513481cad0adf1ae0b225d6167ec690c2bc6d38558cb8ae399ce3bdb
  Peter,99b057c8e3461b97f8d6c461338cf664bc84706b9cc2812daaebf210ea1b9974
  Noroozi,996d7e2bc68410d18cf83438acaf9f8c81db7f7e4dd1c1116b52a1da57beaee3
  Sam,d70ada757917455ce5a436e921854e35871e9e368050c3681c94ca9435c71c66
  MahdimRa,1076c5957d3ea9ffad332d1a3785b90bc658dab676c9ba822c8fe55a3e6c23b4
  Saghi,2876370ec5a463a2b84a7512e3dae1229460b5fe6c31b83ffabf2be977f7247b
  Navid,85432a9890aa5071733459b423ab2aff9f085f56ddfdb26c8fae0c2a04dce84c

4- I read the CSV file then I converted into a dictionary
5- I know my hashes are from 1000-10000
6- Made a dictionary of hashes with keys and values
7-I the only thing I want to do is a simple comparison between two dictionaries.

Comment: you can't compare like this. even for same dictionary test= {'a':'1','b':'2'} test.values() == test.values() returns false

Comment: I thought I can do this type of comparison then I saw Giannis Clipper did it like this:

for key in hash_data:
        if hash_data[key] == bank_of_hash:

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to run your code but couldn't parse the data from hash file to dictionary, so I modified the code to this and worked:

```
import hashlib

hash_data = dict()

with open ('C:\Python\Test\Hash.csv') as hash_file:
    for line in hash_file.read().split():
        hash_data[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1]

for i in range(1000,10000):
    bank_of_hash = hashlib.sha256(str(i).encode()).hexdigest()

    for key in hash_data:
        if hash_data[key] == bank_of_hash:
            print(key, ':', i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it works now.
    So you delete the file_reader = csv.reader(hash_file) there is no need to open that CSV?

So what does this line do:hash_data[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1]
I know you define hash_data as a dictionary but didn't understand this line!

Comment: `with open ('C:\Python\Test\Hash.csv') as hash_file:` => opens the csv file as text file. 

`hash_file.read()` => reads the content of the opened file. 

`hash_file.read().split()` => parse that content line by line to an array.

`line.split(',')[0]` => parse the content of a line to a list and take the first element, the name.

`line.split(',')[1]` => parse the content of a line to a list and take the second element, the hash string. 

`hash_data[line.split(',')[0]] = line.split(',')[1]` => fills the dictionary this way: hash_data['name'] = 'hash_string_here_as_dictionary_value'